# How can I get the element that was right-clicked in a context menu on a NSOutlineView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a `NSOutlineView` and also created a menu that shows up as context menu when I right-click on any element.

Now I have 2 problems.

1. How can I identify the element that was right-clicked in order to act accordingly on any function in the context menu.
2. How can I alter the context menu, before I actually open it to remove or disable an menu item depending on the element that was right-clicked?

Answer (score 1):

The `clickedRow` method (inherited from `NSTableView`) will give you the row number.

The row number can then be transformed to the item using `NSOutlineView`'s `itemForRow`.

For the menu part, the `NSMenuDelegate` method `menu:updateItem:atIndex:shouldCancel:` is called just before the menu is shown, so you can modify it as needed.

According to the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSMenuDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), you also have to implement `numberOfItemsInMenu:`.

You can set the same object as delegate for both the outline view and the menu.

Comment: I added a <NSMenuDelegate> and implemented the <menu:updateItem:atIndex:shouldCancel:> method but the method is not called?! Did I miss anything ?

Comment: <menuWillOpen:> works. I have the delegate to the FileOwner, which is my main ViewController

Comment: used auto-completion "ESC". I´d dismiss a typo.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28502/discussion-between-eemceebee-and-monolo)

Answer (score 0):

In theory, when a row is right-clicked, it should be already the selected row in the NSOutlineView. Anyway, this does not happen normally.

I have solved this, by implementing the following method (that also answers to the second question):

```
- (void)menuNeedsUpdate:(NSMenu *)menu
```

Insert this method in one of your classes and register that class as the menu delegate (please note: the NSMenu, not the single NSMenuItem). In the above code, I have added this piece of code, to automatically select the clicked row when is right clicked.

```
if ([[arrayController selectedObjects] count] == 0 || [[arrayController selectedObjects] count] == 1) {
        if ([myTable clickedRow] != -1) {
            [myTable selectRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[myTable clickedRow]] byExtendingSelection:FALSE];
        }
    }
```

As far as I know, this works correctly inside an NSTableView, so it should work also in your NSOutlineView.

Regarding the second question, you can use the above method to get notified every time the NSMenu is going to be displayed.

Comment: The default behaviour throughout OS X is to not automatically select the item that was clicked by a right mouse click (contextual menu)